# Divide and Conquer (recurrence relation problem)...

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

The problem:

> (a) Use a divide-and-conquer approach to devise a procedure to find the largest
> and next-to-largest numbers in a set of $n$ distinct integers.

> (b) Give a recurrence relation for the number of comparisons performed by your
> procedure.

> (c) Solve the recurrence relation obtained in part (b).

So here's the work I did, with a, b, and c done in 1 swoop:

> Consider $l_1,l_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ and let $L=\max\left\{ {l_1,l_2}\right\}$. Dividing $L$, we compare $l_1,l_2$ now and obtain
> $$a_n=2a_{n/2}+1$$
> for $n \geq 2$ since we have are just comparing the two integers. Using known formulas for the way our $a_n$ looks, we obtain $a_n=An-1$, where if we impose the condition $a_1=1$, we obtain $A=2$ and ultimately
> $$a_n=2n-1.$$

I used an example in the book that was similar to this problem to come to this conclusion, but overall am incredibly confused. I have no idea if I did this correctly. If someone could verify I'm on the right/wrong path, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: What is the procedure you are using?

Comment: Divide and conquer method. There's like 4 formulas you can use based on how your $a_n$ comes out using divide and conquer (well, 4 that our book gives)

Answer (score 1):

For (a), start with 2 values, they are maximum/minimum for the range. If you have $n$ values, split in two as evenly as possible, and get (recursively) largest and runner up for each part, figure out how to combine this for the full $n$ values.

For (b), from the above see what you can use as key operations (so that others are proportional in number), and set up a recurrence according to (a).

Comment: Hmm...that's what I did for (a). I'm thinking maybe I should consider two sets now. Like, $L_1=max\left\{{l_a,l_b}\right\},L_2=max\left\{{l_c,l_d}\right\}$ and then split the sets. We will have $l_a,l_c$ on one half, $l_b,l_d$ on the other. Each set has their own comparisons to find the largest integer, and then we have two more comparisons between the sets to find the next largest integer. Thus, we have 
$$a_n=2a_{\frac{n}{2}} +2$$
if my logic is valid of course. Solving the equation is rather simple from there given the formulas for Divide and Conquer. If my $a_n$ is correct, we have

Comment: $$a_n=\frac{3}{2}n -2$$
if we make our initial condition for $a_2$ is that it's equal to 1